# Understanding conda venv

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, anaconda3

I use this command to create new env:

```
conda create -n topicManager python=3.8 anaconda
```

Then I show list of env by:

```
conda env list
```

I got
[image]
Look at this results I can't understand these things:

1. Why do I have both anaconda and anaconda3 at the same time? What is the difference?
2. What the name on the left means and the name on the right means ?
3. I thought when I type above command it should create name on the left but end up it create on the right as another branch of the one on the left ? What is the right way to create and have a clean environment list from the above ? (It looks quite a mess from the list above I feel ?)

Please help to figure out these unclear points, thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

1. Anaconda is Python 2; Anaconda3 is Python 3.
2. The name on the left is the name of the environment, the name on the right is the directory where that environment is stored on your computer.
3. The way you are creating environments is fine. Also, again, the file path on the right is the directory (folder) that the environment with the name on the left is stored (this holds all the packages that you installed in the environment on the left). The two names really are the same thing; you just access the environment stored at the location on the right with the name on the left.

Comment: So how do I access topicManager that I just created? Looks like it belong to venv while I expect it should belongs to "topicManager " environment ?

Comment: You use `conda activate topicManager`

Comment: @user1314404 If you have both Anaconda 2 and 3 installed, you should keep only one.